# find the minimum chi-square subarray between two arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need a method to find the minimum chi-square pair between two 1D arrays.
For example, one array is

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

another array is

```
b = np.array([0.9, 1, 3.5, 4.5])
```

We need to find a subarray in `b` with the same length of `a` like

```
sub_b = np.array([0.9, 1, 3.5])
```

note the `sub_b` should not include duplicated items.

And to find the closest pair between the two arrays. We choose the `chi-square = sum((a - sub_b)**2) / len(a)`. So, we need to find the `sub_b` with the minimum chi-square.

I use the `iteration.permutations` to find all the permutations of `sub_b` and then find the minimum chi-square.

```
from itertools import permutations

def find_chi2_array(b, a):
    chi2 = lambda x: sum((x-a)**2) / len(a)
    perm = np.array(list(permutations(b, len(a))))
    chi2_results = np.apply_along_axis(chi2, 1, perm)
    return chi2_results.min(), candidates[chi2_results.argmin()]
```

But this method is very stupid and when the length of `b` gets larger, the memory would run out of quickly.

If I use the `for` loop in pure python, the speed is too slow. Can anyone have a more efficient and less memory method?

```
def find_chi2_array_slow(b, a):
    chi2 = lambda x: sum((x-a)**2) / len(a)
    n = 0
    for perm in permutations(b, len(a)):
        perm = np.array(perm)
        n += 1
        if n == 1:
            chi2_result = chi2(perm)
        elif chi2_result > chi2(perm):
            chi2_result = chi2(perm)
    return chi2_result
```